# ¿Cómo hacer determinar tamaño de un array en PHP?

Tags: php, array

Estoy buscando cómo poder determinar el tamaño de un arreglo en **PHP**. En **C#** puedes decir qué tan grande quieres que sea un *array*:

```cs
valores = new int[100];  // 100 elementos.
```

Pero no sé cómo hacerlo en PHP o si se puede al menos.

Comment: Lee la documentación: https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.array.php

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Hola, Andrew. Si lo que quieres sabes es qué tamaño es un _array_ en PHP solo debes utilizar la función `count`. Es decir, `count($array);`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, una disculpa por apenas agradecer no recordaba mi cuenta !!
Buen día !

Answer (score 0):

ten en cuenta que al ser php un lenguaje interpretado no es tan fuertemente tipado como c# por lo tanto lo que quieres hacer tiene mas que ver con la logica que con el lenguaje, podrias usar la funcion count() para obtener el tamaño del array facilemente, pero si lo que quieres es generar un arreglo con un tamaño especifico yo te sugiero que primero declares un array y luego lo llenes con valores de cualquier cosa hasta tener el numero de elementos que deseas, las funciones `range()` o `array_fill()` te podrian servir pero es preferible que uses `count()` para no complicarte.

Comment: Muchas gracias, una disculpa por apenas agradecer no recordaba mi cuenta !! Buen día !